# Graph Theory question: finding the number of vertices from number of edges?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I have no idea how to even begin or think about this. I was thinking of drawing out graphs with that many edges, but the possibilities for complements seem endless.

"Let G be a graph. Now let G'
be the complement graph of G. G' has the same set of vertices as
G, but two vertices x and y in G are adjacent only if x and y are not
adjacent in G
. If G has 15 edges and G'
has 13 edges, how many vertices does G
have? Explain."

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that the sum of the number of edges in the original gragh $G$ and the complement graph $G'$ must be equal to the number of edges in a complete graph with the number of vertices being the number of vertices in $G$. This is because $G'$ will only contain edges not included in $G$.

Thus if the number of vertices in $G$ is $V$, then the total number of edges is $\frac{V(V-1)}{2}$. Since

$$
15+13 = 28 = \frac{56}{2} = \frac{8(8-1)}{2}
$$

Therefore there must be 8 vertices in the graph.

Comment: This is assuming $G$ is complete right?

Comment: @Carpetfizz $G$ doesn't have to be complete, but the sum of the number of edges in the original and the complement must be equal to the total in a complete graph

Answer (score 0):

Think about it this way: $G$ and $G'$ put together form a complete graph $K$ and do not share any of the same edges. Thus $K$ is a complete graph with $15+13 = 28$ edges. This corresponds to [$K_8$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph), since a complete graph has $n(n-1)/2$ edges when it has $n$ vertices ($8 \cdot 7 / 2 = 28$).

Comment: Thank you so much for the help